# Collection view automatic height change

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

Is it possible to automatically change the height of the collection view in relation to the item size. I get the data from the backend and in that data is the configuration for the items. I can adjust the size of the item but I don't know how to change the height of the collection. I want my height to change to be the same as the size of the item (so that the item is fully visible and not cut or smaller)

Answer (score 0):

No it is manage by using uicollectionviewflowlayout delegate.

Comment: yes but with uicollectionviewflowlayout i can adjust the inside of the collection but i don't see a way to tell it to expand as much as itemSize